# How to have checkbox function access table data in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table in `Angularjs` that has a `checkbox` in each row. When the `checkbox` is clicked, I would like an alert function to be launched to display the content of the row being clicked. The problem I face is how can the alert function access the data content of the row?

The table in `html` looks like this;

```
<table class="table table-hover data-table sort display">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Location</th>   
    <th>Checkbox Alert</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in filteredList | orderBy:columnToOrder:reverse">  
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
    <td>{{item.location}}</td>  
    <td> <input type="checkbox" ng-click="alert_display()"> </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The controller code looks like this;

```
$scope.alert_display = function()
{
    alert("Testing");
};
```

I would like `alert_display()` to display the contents of `{{item.name}}` and `{{item.location}}` of the relevant row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="selected" ng-change="display(selected, item)">
```

your JS code:

```
$scope.display = function(selected, item) {

    if(selected)
         alert(item.name + ' ' + item.location);
    else
         // do sth else

}
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/4156/

Comment: Thanks. It works partially. Upvoted but it is not exactly the answer I want. For some reason, I have to check, then uncheck the checkbox in order to launch the display function. How can I get the display function to launch everytime I click the checkbox, regardless of whether I am checking or unchecking it?

Comment: check the fiddle, now it alerts whenever you click | unclick

Comment: You are the man! That's the answer I want! I have marked your answer as the right one. Thanks!!